# Who designed the proposed Space Force logos?

Tags: united-states, military

On August 9, 2018, the Trump administration provided [several proposed logos](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2018/08/trump-wants-campaign-donors-to-vote-on-the-logo-for-the-space-force/) for their planned Space Force. Who designed these logos? Is there some government organization that is tasked with creating logos like this? Or would it be a private sector organization that was contracted for this purpose?

Comment: I can't answer authoritatively on the "Space Force," but the 4 branches of the military (army, navy, air force, marines) do have departments in charge of designing new logos/insignia, etc. For example, the Army has the [Institute of Heraldry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Army_Institute_of_Heraldry), which according to Wikipedia does serve the Executive Office of the President. Though these Space Force logos seem to be logos the *Trump campaign* is pushing to sell Space Force merchandise, in violation of White House ethics.

Comment: @C.Helling "in violation of White House ethics" Add it to the list, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [FastCompany](https://www.fastcompany.com/90216951/trumps-space-force-logos-are-just-as-dumb-as-space-force):

> They weren’t created by anyone at the Pentagon, NASA, or any other federal agency. They were created by the Trump-Pence 2020 campaign PAC.